# Fill missing categorial values using pandas?

Tags: python, missing-data, pandas

I'd like to fill missing categorial cells with new values per column. For example:

```
c1  c2  c3
a   nan  a
b   q    nan
c   d    nan
a   p    z
```

should become something like

```
c1  c2  c3
a   n1   a
b   q    n2
c   d    n2
a   p    z
```

My current problem is that I am using DictVectorizer for categorials column, but it leaves NaNs as-is.

Comment: One method that fills in missing values is called imputation; you might want to read the Amelia II documentation because it describes the missing data problem and one solution in great detail. Moreover, just filling in some mean values is demonstrably a bad idea, and there's some literature on this.

Comment: @amoeba pandas is a Python module that adds data frame functionality similar to R's `data.frame` and `data.table`.

Comment: @Sycorax Yes, I know.

Comment: BTW, want to plug it into wiki excerpt for [pandas], @Sycorax?

Comment: Doesn't the `DataFrame` in `pandas` have a `fillna` method?  You could probably just google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fillna with some uniq string does what you want:

```
categorial_data = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female'],
                                'nationality': ['American', 'European', float('nan'), 'European']})
print(categorial_data)
categorial_data=categorial_data.fillna('some_unique_string')
print('after replacement')
print(categorial_data)
encoder = DV(sparse = False)
encoded_data = encoder.fit_transform(categorial_data.T.to_dict().values())
print(encoded_data)
```

gives you

```
  nationality     sex
0    American    male
1    European  female
2         NaN    male
3    European  female
after replacement
          nationality     sex
0            American    male
1            European  female
2  some_unique_string    male
3            European  female
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```